# What to do when your manager won't give you your annual performance review?

Tags: performance-reviews, performance

My manager is four months late for conducting my performance review. Everyone else I know received it back in July and have already received their salary increase. The deadline for reviews passed a long time ago and employees are not allowed to get their salary reviewed until the performance review has taken place. In addition, people who have their reviews after the review deadline period are not eligible for retroative pay.

Now I am in quite a pickle because I have been asking my manager since June for my review! I've counted that I've asked him over 15 times! Everytime I schedule it he cancels it last minute saying he's too busy or isn't even in his office. I've also asked HR to help me get him to meet two times already, with little effect.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how to approach this now, I am really getting upset.

I am interviewing at other company's right now but really enjoy my current work (except for the terrible manager and the pay), so wish I wouldn't have to even be in this position!

Any thoughts would be helpful! I want to go about this in the right way.

Thanks!

Comment: How did you ask HR? Did you walk over to their cube/office, or just email? Did you follow up?

Comment: HR didn't help you either? I'd guess that they didn't have enough money budgeted to give everyone a raise and you are the person they chose not to give one to and no one in the company has the courage to tell you. It also indicates they think your performance is OK (they would have given you a bad one and fired you by now) but that it is not as good as everyone else's performance. If I wanted to stay, it is that perception I would be worried about. I would be very surprised if you get a pay raise even if you manage to corner him for the eval. I would continue looking for another job.

Comment: I formally went to HR the two times. First to just ask for some help getting him to sit down with me. Then to follow up and say that it's been three months. I don't even think there's enough for a wage increase anymore anyway, senior management meets about a month after the reviews are due and allocates the allocated profits for wage increases.       This might actually be a sign to escape a company with poor management. Going to keep my options open! Thanks!

Comment: In english, what does "I officially feel like if I ask anymore :(." mean?

Comment: lol I wrote that comment and deleted part of it by accident. I meant to say that I would feel like I am being the most massive nag on the face of the planet :P. He will be like "oh my goodness, not this chick again" LOL

Comment: This is my experience - soon after I stop getting regular reviews I look for other employment. It is not worth the hassle, if they don't value you enough to do a simple review.

Comment: @Nadia perhaps you should edit your question so that it reads as you intend, without the confusing sentence... there's an 'edit' button at the bottom left of the question.

Answer (score 11):

Typically you would want to follow your company's chain of command (manager, supervisor, VP, CXO, CEO, etc). If possible double check who the next in line is.

It sounds like you have definitely tried with your manager. I would feel safe approaching their supervisor (or next in line) and *diplomatically* mentioning that you are overdue for a performance review. Make sure they see that you are genuinely wanting to know how you are doing and not that you are trying to get your manager in trouble. If you feel like you are in hot water already, that would be the last thing you'd want to do.

Hopefully they can rectify the situation and defuse any tension you think might be between you and your manager. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your responses! I think I will try the next person up in my department bratak, thanks for the advice! I'm in Ops and the thing that gets me is that all the department managers I work for, like VP Finance and VP Marketing always tell me that they wouldn't know what they would do without me and that I've helped a lot with process and system improvement. But that doesn't matter much if my real manager won't even acknowledge it! Two people have left in the past year and I've fully taken on their workload too, so I'm swamped. -_-

Answer (score 4):

Something sounds strange here. Completing performance reviews is usually a management KPI (key performance indicator - something used to determine performance). While some reviews may be more formal and detailed than others - for some a quick, informal chat is fine - not doing a review is usually frowned on by HR.

Similarly, while many companies may claim salary increases are dictated by performance, in practice they are often unrelated. Upper management usually allocate money for salary increases top down based on budget forecasts and past results and this flows down the management structure to individuals. Performance reviews are, at best, a rationalization.

Considering you have raised this multiple times both with your manager and HR, I suspect one of the following:

1. You are not getting a pay raise and the manager is avoiding a difficult conversation with you. While I think the manager should have this conversation (not having one is only going to make things worse in the future), this does not help you.

   In this case, you need to keep pushing until you get a resolution. As others have suggested, start going up the "chain of command" being polite and constructive.
2. Your manager has bigger problems. Maybe he or she is under pressure to solve an unrelated problem and you are just considered lower priority. Once again, this is the manager's problem - management is the art of balancing the important and urgent - but you are impacted by the situation.

   In this case, you need to identify the other problem(s) and help solve them. This may free the manager up to actually do the performance review.
3. (Unlikely but including for completeness) You are in a role where performance reviews are not done. For example, you could be on a contracted rate rather than a salary. If you are relatively new to the organization, performance reviews may not be done in the first year. I think this is unlikely in your case, since HR probably would have told you this but it is something to consider.

In the meantime, speak to other people in the organization and work out whether others are in the same situation. If this is a pattern, it may help to act *en mass* (as a group). Keep accurate records of conversations, E-mails and meetings. If this does "blow up" into disciplinary action, such records will help. Lastly, keep things civil. You may need your boss or others in the organization as referees or references for future employment.

Ultimately, how important is the pay rise to you? If this is something you desperately need, look elsewhere for a new job. If this is something you can live without, be prepared for it to happen next year.

In my opinion, a performance review is a small investment in time. If they cannot invest the time in you, it is often indicative of the organization's interest in you.

Comment: Hi Everyone,

Just an update in case anyone else is in this situation and is curious.

I submitted a performance review package to him but that wasn't effective.

Next course of action I went to his manager and they didn't realize I hadn't gotten reviewed. They also discovered that his other 2 new employees that were just transferred to him weren't reviewed either. The solution: They transferred me and now I am reporting to my old manager's boss. ha! :) Going up to the next level worked for me.

Thanks for your postings!

Answer (score 2):

Send him a proposal for the performance review, be nicer to yourself than you think is fair, people usually undervalue themselves. Ask if this proposal is okay and if he is that swamped in work, you can do the real review later where he tells you what to improve, but you want your raise now, so he maybe could send it to hr this way already.