# How to plan a performance review

Tags: united-states, performance-reviews

So I started a new job about 3 months ago, and was told that my 3 month review was going to be soon. From all of the words I've gotten from the C-suite, my performance has exceeded all expectations they've had for me, and they are incredibly happy with my work. This includes my manager, who is the controller.

I'd like to see where I can improve, because I never feel like my work is good enough (there's always more to learn), and being a new employee I want to provide even more value to the company. So my 90 days has come and passed, and my boss has said a few times that she'll tell me when my performance review is, but I know her work load is huge, and we haven't had the review yet.

In my last job, I was fleeced into the "We'll look at your performance for a raise at your next review" and was strung along despite O's (highest grade) across the board. I'd understand if they have issues with my performance, or are scared that I'll ask for a raise and don't want to lose the value I provide, but that doesn't sit well with me.

I was told when I joined that there was a lot of extra money for me to grow into after my review period was completed, so it's not a shortage of money that's preventing it. I've been groomed in an environment in which performance reviews are a bit of a taboo subject, but I'd like to bring this to my boss without interrupting her schedule too much. She says that she'll work on it, but if we go too long, I know she'll just let it die, and she doesn't see it as a huge priority.

**How can I schedule my own performance review (which she said she'd call me in for) with my boss?**

Note: If there's any further info you need, I'm here to provide it.

Comment: Could someone please explain the multiple downvotes? Is there something I'm missing, or can do to improve the question?

Comment: Almost a duplicate: [What to do when your manager won't give you your annual performance review?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/35799) (I don't think things have gotten quite as far as they have in that question, but it may still be useful)

Comment: @Anoplexian can you clarify something for me please?  For the scope of this question, are you focused more on professional improvement, or on scoring that raise?

Comment: @Akaioi More of the latter, but the former is definitely a concern. Specifically I want to be more useful to the company, and I believe by doing so the former will follow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Remember managers are people too...

I had a so called boss that hated to give reviews...he dreaded it and he was **NOT good at it at all**. So your boss could be delaying it because he/she also hates to do reviews.

Remember at the end of the day managers are people and people are strange living things.

I got around it by persisting (in a nice manner) that he give me a performance review because he eventually HAD TO. It was company policy. Whether it is company policy for where you work only you know that.  If it is, then you have a winning case.

#### Try something as simple as commenting about it...

You could be just nice about it and phrase it in a way that indicates honesty, sympathy, and a needed response:

> "Hey boss, I know you're tied up with a lot of things but I would
>   appreciate if you could schedule my performance review soon.  I
>   really would like to hear your feedback on how things are going and if
>   you have any questions / concerns with my work."

#### Don't force it...

Don't start forcing it on your boss by auto scheduling the event in your companies email system - then she may think differently about you. Just show that this is something you'd hope would happen and would love to hear the feedback.

#### With time it will naturally happen...

My prior boss had a due date of something like Dec. 7th to have my review done.  He didn't have it finished until February... To me it was unprofessional but I learned that he just despised giving feedback, he actually feared it.  When I heard from other employees that reported to him the same stuff I felt a bit better knowing it wasn't something personal. So have patience!

Answer (score 3):

I think a mistake is being made here ... specifically, the assumption that this kind of feedback and improvement planning is solely done in formal quarterly (or worse!) reviews.

In most companies, manager and report meet up briefly once per week.  It's a good habit to get into, because it means that when that massive review comes along **there are no surprises**.  If you are surprised by something that happens in a perf review, manager is not doing his job.

So ... during this weekly 1-1 meeting ... some topics to address:

- "Hey, how am I doing?"
- "I'm trying to establish some long-term goals.  Can you help?"  If you've already done this, switch to "Here's my status on those goals, ..."

If you haven't been introduced to SMART goals, you should take a look:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMART_criteria

Once you get you and manager into this habit, *it almost doesn't matter* when the large periodic reviews are, because y'all are keeping tabs on goals and status.  Every.  Single.  Week.

Good luck!

Comment: Given the OP's follow up question, (s)he is not actually looking for job feedback, it's about securing a raise.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have some expectations about your review that are, imho, unlikely to happen.

The first review at the 90 day mark is often just a formality.  You haven't been fired so you must be doing a good enough job to keep around.  As you've stated other execs have complimented you.  At this point just settle in and keep doing what you are doing.

> I was told when I joined that there was a lot of extra money for me to
>   grow into after my review period was completed, so it's not a shortage
>   of money that's preventing it.

This part is what worries me.  It sounds like a raise is really what this is about.  I'm pretty sure I've never seen someone receive a raise within their first 90 days at any place I've worked.  You were offered a compensation package just 3 months ago that you accepted.

Modifying that so soon is highly unusual - unless it was actually negotiated prior to accepting the offer.  Which, although rare, would be the only real reason to gently push your boss to set the date for the review.

@JonH has the answer to your stated question.

This was just to point out that if you are expecting a raise at this time you might be in for a bit of a shock.  The vast majority of raises only occur at the annual mark.  Even then it's not entirely automatic as it depends on how the company is doing, how the market is doing in general, how you are currently compensated, etc.  To expect otherwise without an agreement in place beforehand is wishful thinking.

The main reason I've seen for busy managers to ignore the 90 review is that they feel it's an incredibly low priority due to the fact that there is only 1 outcome: ie: you're doing a good enough job to keep around.  If you weren't you would have been replaced during this time.